# How can I store a list of number inside a number in Python?

Tags: python

I need to save a tuple of 4 numbers inside a column that only accepts numbers (int or floats)

I have a list of 4 number like -0.0123445552, -29394.2393339, 0.299393333, 0.00002345556.

How can I "store" all these numbers inside a number and be able to retrieve the original tuple in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Inside a number
x=5
x=(-0.0123445552, -29394.2393339, 0.299393333, 0.00002345556)
Is this what you want to do ?

Comment: For example, I could store 1, 2, 3, 4 as 1234, then I could "unpack" the 1234 as (1, 2, 3, 4). But this example only work with one-digit numbers.

Comment: Why do you want to store 4 numbers in a single number?

Comment: We need more information about your 'column'.

Comment: Because I need to store the 4 numbers in one column of a DB, and the column can't accept tuples, only int or floats.

Comment: how you are storing them . post the code.

Comment: One idea may be to convert the tuple's floats to their binary representation, concatenate them into a big binary number and convert the big binary into a int. Then to unpack, we convert the int to the binary, split the binary into 4 binaries and convert them into a float. Would it work?

Comment: When trying to pack float point numbers you will loose precision, is it OK? Even if you pack 4 large integers using rule from your comment you can overflow, is it OK?

Comment: Yes, the numbers can be represented as a half-precision float (16 bit) so I guess I can fit the 4 numbers inside a 64 bit number?

Comment: Should work, however people will find it hard to support your code. Also if you query your database using any GUI tool then output will be meaningless. It could be better to add additional columns to the table. Maybe you database supports 4-byte float-point numbers, so you do not save too much space by doing this 'compression'

Comment: This is not really python specific.

Comment: Store a reference to a k/v store where you store the actual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on @YevgenYampolskiy's idea of using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

You could use numpy to convert the numbers to 16-bit floats, and then view the array as one 64-bit int:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array((-0.0123445552, -29394.2393339, 0.299393333, 0.00002345556))

stored_int = data.astype('float16').view('int64')[0]
print(stored_int)
# 110959187158999634

recovered = np.array([stored_int], dtype='int64').view('float16')
print(recovered)
# [ -1.23443604e-02  -2.93920000e+04   2.99316406e-01   2.34842300e-05]
```

Note: This requires numpy version 1.6 or better, as this was the first version to support 16-bit floats.

Comment: Thank you very much unutbu. I'm sorry for the odd question!

Answer (score 2):

If by `int` you mean the datatype int in Python (which is unlimited as of the current version), you may use the following solution

```
>>> x
(-0.0123445552, -29394.2393339, 0.299393333, 2.345556e-05)
>>> def encode(data):
    sz_data = str(data)
    import base64
    b64_data = base64.b16encode(sz_data)
    int_data = int(b64_data, 16)
    return int_data

>>> encode(x)
7475673073900173755504583442986834619410853148159171975880377161427327210207077083318036472388282266880288275998775936614297529315947984169L
>>> def decode(data):
    int_data = data
    import base64
    hex_data = hex(int_data)[2:].upper()
    if hex_data[-1] == 'L':
        hex_data = hex_data[:-1]
    b64_data = base64.b16decode(hex_data)
    import ast
    sz_data = ast.literal_eval(b64_data)
    return sz_data

>>> decode(encode(x))
(-0.0123445552, -29394.2393339, 0.299393333, 2.345556e-05)
```

Comment: Overflow... Oracle NUMBER type stores integers up-to 38 character, for instance

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy: No where in the Original Question, did they mention about database, and what `int` means, in Python `int` is unlimited

Comment: Read comments to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can combine 4 integers into a single integer, or two floats into a double using `struct` module:

```
from struct import *
s = pack('hhhh', 1, -2, 3,-4)
i = unpack('Q', pack('Q', i[0]))
print i
print unpack('hhhh', s)

s = pack('ff', 1.12, -2.32)
f = unpack('d', s)
print f
print unpack('ff', pack('d', f[0]))
```

prints

```
(18445618190982447105L,)
(1, -2, 3, -4)
(-5.119999879002571,)
(1.1200000047683716, -2.319999933242798)
```

Basically in this example tuple (1,-2,3,-4) gets packed into an integer 18445618190982447105, and tuple ( 1.12, -2.32) gets packed into -5.119999879002571

To pack 4 floats into a single float you will need to use half-floats, however this is a problem here:

With half-float it looks like there is no native support in python as of now:
http://bugs.python.org/issue11734

However `numpy` module do have some support for half-floats (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html). Maybe you can use it somehow to pack 4 floats into a single float

Answer (score 0):

my idea is weird; but will it work??

```
In [31]: nk="-0.0123445552, -29394.2393339, 0.299393333, 0.00002345556"

In [32]: nk1="".join(str(ord(x)) for x in nk)

In [33]: nk1
Out[33]: '454846484950515252535353504432455057515752465051575151515744324846505757515751515151443248464848484850515253535354'

In [34]: import math

In [35]: math.log(long(nk1), 1000)
Out[36]: 37.885954947611985

In [37]: math.pow(1000,_)
Out[37]: 4.548464849505043e+113
```

you can easily unpack this string(`Out[33]`); for example split it at `32`; its for `space`.

also this string is very long; we can make it to a small number by `math.log`; as we got in `Out[36]`.

Comment: How would you get the original ``nk`` out of the last one?

Comment: You will try to store '454846484950515252535353504432455057515752465051575151515744324846505757515751515151443248464848484850515253535354' in a float? It will overflow

Comment: yes it will overflow.. .!!! may be it can be down by converting it to another base.. .???

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy: so can to put this long value as `log`??? see the updated post; `Out[36]`???

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer your question, but what you're trying to do violates [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Is changing the DB schema to introduce an intersection table really not an option?

Comment: Yes, that would make everything easier! But I can't change the schema. I only can read and write rows. Thanks